# Error Code 200 phpmyadmin 4.6.0

Tags: php, mysql, windows, phpmyadmin

Currently on phpmyadmin version 4.6.0, getting the error message "Error in processing request Error Code: 200 Error Text: OK" when attempting to create a table. I tried restarting the server as another thread suggested that solution, no luck. I tried changing the language as well, nothing. Currently running Windows 10 x64bit. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That can be a [CSP](https://content-security-policy.com/) configuration problem, to check it, verify your console in your browser devtools